# Как пользоваться npm в оффлайн-режиме?

Tags: npm, angular2

Хочу написать небольшое SPA на Angular2. Все туториалы указывают на необходимость использования npm. Однако на машине нет подключения к интернет. В случае с nuget я просто скачивал пакеты в локальную папку на диске, а затем указывал путь к этой папке для установки пакета в проект. А как в таком случае быть с npm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Некоторое время назад тоже столкнулся с подобной задачей. Мне помогло [такое](https://addyosmani.com/blog/using-npm-offline/) решение.

**UPD**

Утилита `local-npm` позволяет создать локальное зеркало npm-репозитория. Для его установки используем следующую команду:

```
npm install -g local-npm
```

Кроме того, для установки необходимо наличие на машине Python'а 2.7 и компилятора c/c++. В моем случаи это Visual Studio Community Edition (поскольку, я делал установку под Windows).

В моем случаи надо было организовать локальный репозиторий в рамках локальной сети, поэтому сервер запускался так:

```
local-npm --url-base http://192.168.x.x:5080
```

`--url-base` можно не задавать, тогда сервер поднимется на `http://localhost:5080`.

Далее, устанавливаем локальный репозиторий для `npm`:

```
npm set registry http://127.0.0.1:5080
```

или

```
npm set registry http://192.168.x.x:5080
```

Для первоначального кеширования пакетов создаем фиктивный `package.json`, в который прописываем все необходимые зависимости и выполняем

```
npm install
```

в дальнейшем, при отсутствии интернета, пакеты будут ставится из кеша.

Тут есть одно небольшое замечание. Мой случай несколько отличается от вашего, поскольку задача состояла в том что бы кешировать пакеты на одной машине - сервере, который **имел** доступ к интернету, и в случаи отсутствия каких либо пакетов в кеше, он их оперативно подтягивал из сети. Все остальные машины в локальной сети были без доступа к интернету.

Comment: Но ведь после запуска local-npm, он сразу же начинает реплицировать skimdb в локальный PouchDB-сервер. Т.е., насколько я понимаю, он скачивает всю базу npm? ПОлучается, я могу после завершения репликации отключить свой локальный сервер от интернета и пользоваться локальной базой?

Comment: В принципе - да. Репликация идет по текущему временному сразу. Если у вас не будут меняться модули или их версии, то интернет не нужен. Хотя я не проверя, на сколько полон локальный репозиторий, поэтому и создавал фиктивный packege.json, дабы необходимые мне модули гарантированно прокешировались.

Comment: А обновление локального репозитория происходит автоматически, когда сервер подключен к интернету? Или необходимо выполнять какую-то команду?

Comment: Автоматически, он сам следит за изменениями и при необходимость делает обновление локального репозитория.